# Как унаследовать интерфейс от класса?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть два класса, наследника стандартных элементов управления [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms). Оба класса реализуют мой интерфейс `IMyControl`

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl, IMyControl
{   
   public void Foo1 (int int1, int int2)
   {
       //реализация Foo1 
   }
   public void Foo2 (string string1)
   {
       //реализация Foo2
   }
}

public class MyPanel : Panel, IMyControl
{   
   public void Foo1 (int int1, int int2)
   {
       //реализация Foo1 
   }
   public void Foo2 (string string1)
   {
       //реализация Foo2
   }
}

public interface IMyControl
{   
   void Foo1 (int int1, int int2);
   void Foo2 (string string1);
}
```

Теперь мне нужно реализовать класс-хэлпер следующего вида

```
public class MyControlHelper<T> where T : IMyControl
{
     public void BuildTo(Control body, T child)
     {
         body.Controls.Add(child);
     }
}
```

Хорошо, я знаю что мои классы реализующие `IMyControl` можно добавить в дочерние к иному контролу. Но компилятор не знает. Хорошо, значит надо указать, что мой интерфейс включает `IControl` и всего делов

```
public interface IMyControl : IControl
{   
   void Foo1 (int int1, int int2);
   void Foo2 (string string1);
}
```

Ой. Но интерфейса `IControl` в [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) почему-то нет. А какой же тип принимает в качестве параметра метод `Control.Controls.Add` ? Оказывается он принимает тип класса `Control`.
Вот это уже как-то нехорошо... Может интерфейс в [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) всё-таки может включать "интерфейс класса"?

```
public interface IMyControl : Control
{   
   void Foo1 (int int1, int int2);
   void Foo2 (string string1);
}
```

Увы, нет (Что сложно было сделать?!)

Так как же мне реализовать `MyControlHelper` ?

Comment: `public class MyControlHelper<T> where T : UserControl, IMyControl`

Comment: @tym32167, да уж очень просто. Хорошо, если оформите ответ, только не `UserControl`, а `Control`

Comment: Павел уже написал, отметье его ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой способ - поставить второе ограничение там, где это требуется:

```
public class MyControlHelper<T> where T : Control, IMyControl
{
     public void BuildTo(Control body, T child)
     {
         body.Controls.Add(child);
     }
}
```

В тех же местах, где такой вариант неприемлем - можно оставить только наиболее важное ограничение, а остальные сделать опциональными:

```
public void BuildTo(Control body, Control child)
{
    body.Controls.Add(child);
}

public IEnumerable<IMyControl> GetMyControls(Control body)
{
    // Нас интересуют только IMyControl, на остальные просто не обращаем внимания
    return body.Controls.OfType<IMyControl>();
}
```

Более сложный вариант - инвертировать логику добавления: пусть контрол сам думает как правильно добавиться к родителю.

```
public interface IMyControl 
{   
   void AttachTo(Control body);       

   void Foo1 (int int1, int int2);
   void Foo2 (string string1);
}

public class MyControlHelper<T> where T : IMyControl
{
     public void BuildTo(Control body, T child)
     {
         child.AttachTo(body);
     }
}
```

Но тут надо помнить о том, что контрол вполне может сделать эту операцию как-то нестандартно, а потому надо хранить дополнительную коллекцию `IMyControl` если в дальнейшем требуется добавленные таким образом контролы достать обратно:

```
public interface IMyControl 
{   
   void AttachTo(Control body);       

   void Foo1 (int int1, int int2);
   void Foo2 (string string1);
}

public class MyControlHelper<T> where T : IMyControl
{
     static readonly ConditionalWeakTable<Control, List<T>> 
         childs = new ConditionalWeakTable<Control, List<T>>();

     public void BuildTo(Control body, T child)
     {
         child.AttachTo(body);
         childs.GetOrCreateValue(body).Add(child);
     }

     public IEnumerable<T> GetChilds(Control body) 
         => childs.GetOrCreateValue(body);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно добавить в интерфейс метод `AsControl()`

```
public interface IMyControl 
{   
   Control AsControl();
   void Foo1 (int int1, int int2);
   void Foo2 (string string1);
}
```

реализацию метода будет простая

```
public Control AsControl()
{
   return this as Control;   
}
```

код хэлпера, изменится лишь немного

```
public class MyControlHelper<T> where T : IMyControl
{
     public void BuildTo(Control body, T child)
     {
         body.Controls.Add(child.AsControl());
     }
}
```

## UPD

Ну и в отличии от варианта [от tym32167](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/746040/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0#comment1145485_746040) здесь всё-таки вешается обязанность приводится к интерфейсу типа `Control`, на классы реализующие `IMyControl`, а не откладывается соответствие обязанности до вызова метода хэлпера.

Comment: Не самый лучший вариант, поскольку интерфейс никак не гарантирует что `child.AsControl() == child`. Если вы добавляете таким образом контрол в коллекцию, а потом ожидаете его оттуда достать и привести к `IMyControl` - могут всплыть сюрпризы в будущем.

Comment: Если вам надо, чтобы все наследуемые типы наследовали тип Control, то используйте абстрактный класс вместо интерфейса

Comment: @tym32167 нет. Мне надо, чтоб мои типы наследовали конкретных наследников `Control` и поэтому мне абстрактный класс, увы, не подойдёт.

Comment: Если ваши типы будут наследовать абстрактный класс, которой наследует Control, то ваши типы автоматом наследуют Control. Или я чего не понял

Comment: @tym32167 Мне надо, чтоб мои типы наследовали конкретных наследников `Control` : `Panel`, `UserControl` и т.д.

Comment: @PavelMayorov попытался обойти указанные Вами ограничения с помощью дженерик-ада https://pastebin.com/fmHtiDDW (:

Comment: При таком обходе вы теряете возможность полиморфизма - единственное преимущество перед простейшим указанием двойного ограничения `where T : Control, IMyControl`

Comment: Вы не можете запретить другим классам реализовать интерфейс. Абстрактный класс вам тоже не подходит. Потому ограничение, что предложили вам я и Павел - самый нормальный выход